# Deduce template type from lambda invocation on container

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

I have the following map implementation that takes a vector and a lambda as input and returns a new vector.

```
template <typename R, typename T, typename Predicate>
std::vector<R> map(const std::vector<T> &v, Predicate p) {
    std::vector<R> mapd(v.size());
    std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), mapd.begin(), p);
    return mapd;
}
```

Which I use in the following way

```
std::vector<int> input{1, 2, 3};
auto result = map<float>(input, [] (const int &v) { return v * 2.0; }); // result should be vector<float>{2., 4., 6.}
```

This works, but I want to see if I can deduce the R template type without specifying it in the call.

Now, I know that I have both the return type of the lambda and the type of the input vector, is there a way to do this? I've tried using `std::result_of_t<p(t)>`  but got nowhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something as follows ?

```
template <typename T, typename Predicate, 
          typename R = decltype(std::declval<Predicate>()(std::declval<T>()))>
std::vector<R> map(const std::vector<T> &v, Predicate p) {
    std::vector<R> mapd(v.size());
    std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), mapd.begin(), p);
    return mapd;
}
```

Or maybe (if you can use at least C++14)

```
template <typename T, typename Predicate>
auto map(const std::vector<T> &v, Predicate p) {
    std::vector<decltype(p(v[0]))> mapd(v.size());
    std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), mapd.begin(), p);
    return mapd;
}
```

Comment: Yeah pretty much I expected something like the first version. Its missing a parenthesis at the end of the decltype I think.

Comment: @Aram - oh, yes... you're right: parenthesis corrected.

Comment: Dumb question, does the second version work if v is an empty vector? (It seems so but I don't get why)

Comment: @Aram `decltype` doesn't care. It doesn't evaluate the expression - it yields the type.

Comment: @Aram - yes: works because `decltype()` is interested only in types and is decided compile-time.